# MyWpfExtension.vb gets an "Overload Resolution Failed" after adding projects

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I had a few projects I needed to add into my main projects and am now getting an error in the MyWpfExtension.vb file in the Partial Class Application

> Overload Resolution Failed because no 'New' is accessible

```vb
Partial Class Application
    Inherits Windows.Application

    <SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")> _
    <SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic")>
    Friend ReadOnly Property Info As AssemblyInfo
        <DebuggerHidden>
        Get
            Return New AssemblyInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()) 'Error here
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The error is where I commented. It is throwing an error when it attempts to return New AssemblyInfo.

Need some help as I can't get this to compile now, even though everything else is working.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you have added something that includes a class called `AssemblyInfo`, which expect different parameters and is not the one you were after anyway.

If I had to guess, the class you want is the [**`Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). To be sure that you're using that specific one, you can reference the class via its entire namespace instead:

```
<SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")> _
<SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic")>
Friend ReadOnly Property Info As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo
    <DebuggerHidden>
    Get
        Return New Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AssemblyInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: I didn't add anything to this at all, this was either autogenerated or is now throwing an error due to there being something conflicting...I'll have to look into it more

Comment: @MattE : Not to this specific file, but you said you were adding a few projects to your main project. One of these could have included a class called `AssemblyInfo`. Try changing it per my answer and see if it works.

Comment: Ended up being an issue with one of the NuGet Packages that was overriding the AssemblyInfo class with its own definition...once I removed the package it reverted back to the original and the error was gone